# unity не двигается объект

Tags: unity3d

я недавно начал изучать юнити и попытался написать скрипт движения по памяти. но коробка просто не двигается. я пробовал разные методы, ни один не работает.

код:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;
using UnityEngine;


public class move : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;
    public float jumppower;
    public bool onground;
    private Vector2 moveDirection = Vector2.zero;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        speed = 5;
        jumppower = 5;
        onground = true;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (onground)
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D))
            {
                moveDirection.x = speed;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Вместо moveDirection.x = speed; нужно вставить transform.Translate(speed, 0, 0);

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Translate.html

Comment: теперь он двигается, но телепортируется. в принципе можно сделать рогалик) спасибо!!